Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ISitecoreItemProxy' to type 'Projecr.Navigation.IFooter_Navigation_Group'
I'm working on the Sitecore upgrade from 8.2 to 10.4. i'm facing the below issue to cast.
System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ISitecoreItemProxy' to type 'Project.Navigation.IFooter_Navigation_Group'.
  Source=App_Web_ufphucso
  StackTrace:
   at ASP._Page_Areas_Project_Views_Renderings_Shared_Footer_LinkSections_cshtml.Execute() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\pri.localsc.dev.local\Areas\XRite\Views\Renderings\Shared\Footer\LinkSections.cshtml:line 18

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    ASP._Page_Areas_XRite_Views_Renderings_Shared_Footer_LinkSections_cshtml.Execute() in LinkSections.cshtml

Could you please suggest the answer.

Here is the solution LinkSections.cshtml and the main hightlight here we need to create the MVCContext and conversion need to be performed
@{
    IMvcContext mvcContext = new MvcContext();
}

var childItem = mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<IFooter_Navigation_Group>(navGroup.Id);
var groupItem = (IFooter_Navigation_Group)childItem;

